# I am trying to set up a Minecraft server on a raspberry pi but I keep encountering an error when first starting the server

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I am able to set the pi up with ssh, get the required BuiltTools.jar setup up and spigot downloaded. However, when I start the server (after agreeing to EULA) I encounter this error:

"Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Server console handler"

This stops the world from being generated and it does not continue. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Please read the [help].  If it's not about programming or tools used for programming then it's off-topic here.  There are plenty of other places on the Internet where this would be on-topic, though.

Comment: Java edition is a no go, but there's hope. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is unambiguous: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` means that you don't have enough memory for Java Minecraft to run, and unfortunately, your situation is fatal.

Your Raspberry Pi is running a 32-bit operating system, meaning no single process can consume more than 2 GB of RAM. Minecraft Java Edition recommends a minimum of 8 GB RAM with a 64-bit OS, which can address at least 1 TB of RAM

Unless you switch to a PC with a 64-bit OS, you're pretty much out of luck.

EDIT: Unless... you use the [Raspberry Pi edition](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/edition/pi/) of Minecraft.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to launch java server jar with `java -Xmx64m` which will set the max heap size